# Espaço abaixo de div com imagem

Tags: html, css

Em HTML e CSS está aparecendo um espaço branco abaixo da imagem, veja o exemplo, o erro é esse espaço branco entre a imagem e a caixa preta

```css
.div1{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
.div2{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/stNlx.jpg">
</div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Como resolver?

Comment: opá, vc pode colocar um margin-bottom: -4px; para resolver inicialmente...

Comment: você pode tentar assim também, colocando esse style na div1...

width: 100%;
    height: 195px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/stNlx.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 70% auto;

Comment: @RobertCezar Inserir uma imagem utilizando a tag `<img>` é completamente diferente de inserí-la como *background* de um elemento. Não são soluções equivalentes e, portanto, uma não substitui a outra.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss estou ciente amigo, apenas uma forma caso ele queira explorar... só esqueci de dizer que ele deve retirar a tag <img> caso a use.